# Passport and connect-flash: req.flash is not a function

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm learning `flash` messaging in `passport` and got stuck on this error when running my script:

```
req.flash is not a function
```

Here is my configuration:

```
var flash=require("connect-flash");
app.use(flash());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(req,username, password,done) {
process.nextTick(function() {
    UserDetails.findOne({'username': username}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }          
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false,req.flash('message','Invalid username or password'));
        }
        if (user.password != password) {
            return done(null, false,req.flash('message','Invalid username or password' ));
        }
        return done(null, user);
    });
});
}));
```

My route:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.render('login',{ message: req.flash('message') });
});
```

My strategy:

```
app.post('/login', function(req,res,next){
passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/')}
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); } 
            arenderFunction(req,res);
        });
    })
(req, res, next);
});
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The request object isn't passed to the strategy callback by default, you need to set the `passReqToCallback` option for this:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  passReqToCallback : true
}, function(req, username, password, done) { ... }));
```

This is documented [here](http://passportjs.org/docs#association-in-verify-callback).

Comment: @AryehArmon care to elaborate? I assume that you have properly installed and configured [`connect-flash`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash)?

Comment: i just found my error, i had to include app.use(flash()); before the post middle ware. i was able to get it working without add the passReqToCallback

Answer (score 9):

Set flash before the app.router

```
app.use(express.cookieParser()); 
app.use(express.session({ secret: "secret" }));

//app.use(passport.initialize());
//app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions

app.use(flash());
app.use(app.router);
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not notice that my  app.use('/abc', abc);  was before app.use(flash());    I moved it after it and it worked.

Comment: Your code indicates that it goes before app.router, your text the opposite